# Monte Carlo approach in a distribution of a loss process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, risk, actuarial-science

I am trying to estimate the next quantity using Monte Carlo method.

I have the next well-known quantity called the  Crámer-Lundberg risk process, given by the expression 
$$Y_t=x+ct-Z_t$$
where $Z_t=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N_t}X_i$ is a compound Poisson process, i.e $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent identically distributed random losses, and $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a compound Poisson process.

Y define the maximal agreggated loss as: $$S=\displaystyle\sup_{t\geq 0}\{L_t\}$$ with $L_t=Z_t-ct$.
In the context (actuarial risk context) that I am studying is the loss minus the new capital of the insurance company.

I am interested in the next quantity:
$$\inf\{x\geq 0|F_S(x)\geq1-\epsilon\}$$

Now since is difficult to know the distribution of $S$ I am going to use the Monte Carlo method. In order to do that I consider the empirical distribution function given by $$\hat{F_S}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum{\mathbb{1}_\{S\geq x\}}$$

Then, since my problem is reduced to compute a quantile, I consider the suggestion of a topic that I asked before 
[Monte Carlo Estimator for a quantile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308432/monte-carlo-estimator-for-a-quantile)

I should solve $$\hat{F_S}(x)-(1-\epsilon)=0$$ using some numerical procedure.

I have the next questions:
1) Is Ok my usage of the Monte Carlo method in this case?, because I am a little bit confused with the random variable $S$ where is taken into account the supremum of its definition (actually I am not clear also why in the Monte Carlo approach for a quantile there is no at some stage the infimum)? or How to consider it in the Monte Carlo approach?

2)In order to perform simulations by example which value of $ct$ could I use in the Cráme-Lundberg Model? (for practical purposes), I think for instance use $c=1$ it means that for every $t$ this quantity will increase one. It is ok my interpretation?